# add a new column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  one data frame and I want to add one more column

the data frame has `29793` rows. So I want the new column to goes down to the end of the data frame

I try some things. in the begging a declare the column and the value like `activity = ["sitting"]`

then I try to add to the existing data frame

```
a['activity'] = activity
```

but I get the following error

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match the length of the index
```

how to fix this. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Is there a way to add the column in the begging of the data frame (left side) because now is appended in the right side

Comment: do you need use `activity` variable? Or `a['activity'] = 'sitting'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set new column by scalar by select first value in one element list:

```
activity = ["sitting"]
a['activity'] = activity[0]
```

Or remove `[]` for scalar:

```
activity = "sitting"
a['activity'] = activity
```

EDIT:

Use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for create new column from left side, in position `0`:

```
a.insert(0, 'activity', activity)
```

what is same like:

```
a.insert(0, 'activity', "sitting")
```

Comment: yeap that works.is there a way to add the column in the begging of the data frame (left side) because now is appended in the right side

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
a['activity'] = 'sitting'
```